# C++ Segmentation fault with no pointers (g++)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a segmentation fault without using any pointers. (I'm using the gcc g++ compiler on)

The code (only the function where I get the error):

```
void printBoard(int boardOwn[][10], int boardState[][10],  int boardType[][10])
{

    char ownerOutput[3][2] = { {' ',' '}, { '*','X' }, { 'o','0' } };
    char stateOutput[5][2] = { {' ', ' '}, {'-', '-'}, { '[', ']' }, {'>', '<'}, {'!', '!'} };

    char verDivider = '|';
    std::string horDivider = "---";

    char characters[10] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H' , 'I', 'J'};

    std::cout << "\n\n\n\t";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << ' ' << characters[i] << "  ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";


    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
    {
        std::cout << ' ' << y + 1 << '\t';

        for (int x0 = 0; x0 < 10; x0++)
        {

            std::cout << stateOutput[boardState[y][x0]][0] << ownerOutput[boardOwn[y][x0]][boardType[y][x0]]<< stateOutput[boardState[y][x0]][1];

            if (x0 != 9)
            {
                std::cout << verDivider;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << '\n';
            }
        }

        if (y != 9)
        {
            std::cout << '\t';
            for (int x1 = 0; x1 < 10; x1++)
            {
                std::cout << horDivider;
                if (x1 != 9)
                {
                    std::cout << verDivider;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << '\n';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n\n";
}
```

if i comment out the:

`std::cout << stateOutput[boardState[y][x0]][0] << ownerOutput[boardOwn[y][x0]][boardType[y][x0]]<< stateOutput[boardState[y][x0]][1];` 
line then the program works fine, but it doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the line since any cout statement in this position will cause the segfault.
Also if the boardOwn, boardState and boardType are declared and used as  2 dimentional 8*8 arrays (rather than 10*10)... then it also works fine. And I did check if the arrays are declared correctly. Here is the code when i declare them:

```
enum BoardObjectOwn { NONE_OWN, P1_OWN, P2_OWN };
enum BoardObjectStates {NORMAL_STATE, OWNED_STATE, SELECTED_STATE, POTENTIAL_LOCATION_STATE, UNDER_ATK_STATE};
enum BoardObjectsTypes {MAN_TYPE, KINGED_TYPE};

int boardOwn[10][10];
int boardState[10][10];
int boardType[10][10];


for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) 
{
    for (int x = 10; x < 10; x++) 
    {
        if (y != 4 && y != 5) 
        {
            if (y % 2 == 0) 
            {
                if (x % 2 == 0) 
                {
                    if (y < 5) 
                    {
                        boardOwn[y][x] = P1_OWN;
                        boardState[y][x] = NORMAL_STATE;
                        boardType[y][x] = MAN_TYPE;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        boardOwn[y][x] = P2_OWN;
                        boardState[y][x] = NORMAL_STATE;
                        boardType[y][x] = MAN_TYPE;
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    boardOwn[y][x] = NONE_OWN;
                    boardState[y][x] = NORMAL_STATE;
                    boardType[y][x] = MAN_TYPE;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                if (x % 2 != 0)
                {
                    if (y < 5)
                    {
                        boardOwn[y][x] = P1_OWN;
                        boardState[y][x] = NORMAL_STATE;
                        boardType[y][x] = MAN_TYPE;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        boardOwn[y][x] = P2_OWN;
                        boardState[y][x] = NORMAL_STATE;
                        boardType[y][x] = MAN_TYPE;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    boardOwn[y][x] = NONE_OWN;
                    boardState[y][x] = NORMAL_STATE;
                    boardType[y][x] = MAN_TYPE;
                }
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            boardOwn[y][x] = NONE_OWN;
            boardState[y][x] = NORMAL_STATE;
            boardType[y][x] = MAN_TYPE;
        }
    }
}
```

and then when I call the printBoard function:

```
printBoard(boardOwn, boardState, boardType);
```

Also I'm using the gcc g++ compiler and I normally don't get any errors but if i add the -Wall then i get the following errors:

```
pp
draughts.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
draughts.cpp:74:16: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
    EXIT_SUCCESS;
                ^
draughts.cpp: In function ‘void game()’:
draughts.cpp:209:8: warning: variable ‘XCord’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    int XCord;
        ^
```

none of those seem to be related to my problem.

I've never seen this error and i really don't know how to troubleshoot it so please help.

thank you.

Klemen

P.S. if you need to see more of my code i'll surely post it.

Comment: You *are* using pointers, you just don't know about them. Arrays decay to pointers.

Comment: I might start by not using `char*` or `char []` at all when writing C++.

Comment: Look up null termination in C. This will be helpful if you choose not to use `std::string`.

Comment: so you are saying i should just use string rather than character arrays ?

Comment: YES!!!! Please do. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your program , array  boardOwn ,boardState, boardType are not initialized at all .
Reason is below for loop which is redundant .

```
for (int x = 10; x < 10; x++)
```

You intialized x with 10 and condition is x<10 .It will never execute and hence all array boardOwn ,boardState, boardType will not be initialised and it will contain junk values .
I think you wanted this loop as `for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)` .

Now you are passing same array in `printBoard` function .
Accessing  `std::cout << stateOutput[boardState[y][x0]][0]` is segmentation fault as `boardState[y][x0]` will have junnk value as it is not initialised .Similarly look for other array .